# Links to alter location within div

Tags: html, css

My page consists of 2 divs that are next to each other.

Say the div on the left is a book with different chapters.

I want my links in the right div to move the content within the div to have the clicked chapter at the top (Basically to scroll down to that chapter.

There is probably a simple answer for this i'm missing,

Any help would be great.

Comment: You have to show your work that you have tried so far, see there is huge going on handling these type of question [**Should Stack Overflow reward effort?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort?cb=1).  So don't fall under that category.

Comment: Just wanted a quick answer, so didn't feel the need to. It states clearly in my question what i want, so people that know html/css would be able to answer it in 30 seconds.

Comment: But without code we wouldn't be able to see what you have tried and then we maybe answer something that you have already tried. And maybe you have something in your code and then we wouldn't know that.

Comment: I normally do add code, One of my other questions (About XML) was quite a detailed question with lots of effort and code snippets, but wasn't answered. BBut i know for next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="text">
    <h1 id="chapterone">Chapter one</h1>
    <p>The text of chapter 1</p>
    <h1 id="chaptertwo">Chapter two</h1>
    <p>The text of chapter 2</p>
    <h1 id="chapterthree">Chapter three</h1>
    <p>The text of chapter 3</p>
</div>
<div id="links">
    <a href="#chapterone">Chapter one</a>
    <a href="#chaptertwo">Chapter two</a>
    <a href="#chapterthree">Chapter three</a>
</div>
```

If you arw using iFrames take a look into [jQuery ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: @BigJayMalcolm Pleasure, and remember to tick it.

Comment: Yeah was just waiting the 2 minutes until i could :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this would be using href. This will only work if you are building the "book" using HTML and it's not an image or PDF or whatnot.

Give the header of each chapter a unique id like "ch1", "c2", etc.

Then set the href links Chapter 1

```
<div id="left">
    <h1 id="ch1">
    <h2 id="ch2">
    #etc
 </div>
 <div id="right">
    <a href="#ch1">Chapter 1</a>
    <a href = "#ch2">Chapter 2</a>
    #etc
 </div>
```

Mind you this only works if the "book" is HTML. If it is iframed in or is an image then look into the jQuery plugin Scrollto which will allow you to set scroll heights (in pixels) for each element you want to scroll to.

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `href` and make it work.`href` and `id` of the chapter title should be same. So that it will navigate to the particular title.

```
<div> <!-- for links-->
<a href="#firstChapter">FirstChapter </a>
<a href="#secondChapter">Second Chapter </a>
<a href="#lastChapter">Last Chapter </a>
</div>
<div> <!-- for Chapters -->
<h1 id="firstChapter"> Chapter 1</h1>
<p>Content of chapter   </p>
<h1 id="secondChapter"> Chapter 2</h1>
<p>Content of chapter   </p>
<h1 id="lastChapter"> Chapter 10</h1>
<p>Content of chapter   </p>
</div>
```